# How to print a list of tokenized text into a file

Tags: python

```
 from urllib import request
    from redditscore.tokenizer import CrazyTokenizer
    tokenizer = CrazyTokenizer()
    url = "http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~diana/csi5386/A1_2020/microblog2011.txt"
    for line in request.urlopen(url):
        tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(line.decode('utf-8'))
        #print(tokens)
    with open('your_file.txt', 'a') as f:
        print(tokens)
        for item in tokens:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

In the above code my output is in variable tokens in the form of list.

Output sample:

```
['\ufeffsave', 'bbc', 'world', 'service', 'from', 'savage', 'cuts'] 
['a', 'lot', 'of', 'people', 'always', 'make', 'fun', 'about', 'the', 'end', 'of', 'the', 'world', 'but', 'the', 'question', 'is', '"are', 'u', 'ready', 'for', 'it'] 
['rethink', 'group', 'positive', 'in', 'outlook', 'technology', 'staffing', 'specialist', 'the', 'rethink', 'group', 'expects', 'revenues', 'to', 'be']
```

Now i'm trying to print this output into a text file.

How can i do that? please help..

Comment: What are you getting in your file ?

Comment: Are you getting some error ? What is the problem you are facing with your code?

Comment: And ? What's your issue exactly ???

Comment: NB: note that with your current code you will only get the tokens from the very last line of the source text.

Comment: Yes i'm only getting only last line of output. But i need all of my output to be printed to file. how do i do that? @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: @john is _this_ your actual problem ? Only getting the last token ??? If yes the issue is pretty obvious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'a') as f:
    for line in request.urlopen(url):
        tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(line.decode('utf-8'))
        #print(tokens)
        for item in tokens:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `' '.join` with each token item

like the following (I am assuming that I already have the data in an array):

```
tokens = [
    ['\ufeffsave', 'bbc', 'world', 'service', 'from', 'savage', 'cuts'],
    ['a', 'lot', 'of', 'people', 'always', 'make', 'fun', 'about', 'the', 'end', 
     'of', 'the', 'world', 'but', 'the', 'question', 'is', '"are', 'u', 'ready', 
     'for', 'it'],
    ['rethink', 'group', 'positive', 'in', 'outlook', 'technology', 'staffing', 
     'specialist', 'the', 'rethink', 'group', 'expects', 'revenues', 'to', 'be']
]
with open('your_file.txt', 'a') as f:
    print(tokens)
    for item in tokens:
        f.write("%s\n" % ' '.join(item))
```

Comment: Like my output is way bigger than that. I just posted a sample of it. I'm tokenizing more than 40000 lines. So how to print all that into a file. @radwan abu odeh